# Why No Statistics Data at the Lower Bar?

Tags: interface

There used to be vertex, face etc. numbers at this lower bar.

Why is this not appearing?
Is there a way to get it back?

PS: I'm not asking about statistics in the Overlay menu.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

right click on the bar -> check "scene statistics"

[image]